# GitKraken pre-commit fails but works in command line commit

Tags: javascript, git, github

I'm trying to commit any kind of change to a branch in my repository using GitKraken and get the following error every time:

[image]

whats strange is if I run `git commit -m 'test'` it commits without any errors. If I comment out the below line in my package.json then I can make commits in GitKraken no problem:

```
"precommit": "yarn check --integrity && lint-staged",
```

The person i've inherited the project from uses an Apple machine and he isn't experiencing any issues like this so not sure if that could be related. I'm also using node v8.9.4 and yarn v1.5.1

I've also tried deleting the yarn lock & node modules folder but still the same result. Anyone have an idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue, might be the answer, it has to do with the shell GitKraken uses by default in Windows:

https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/243